# telegram api send message return nothing

Tags: php, curl, telegram, telegram-bot, php-telegram-bot

I want to send message via `telegram api` but it's not working, and not send any message. this is what i tried so far:

```
function sendTelegram($chatID, $msg) {
echo "sending message to " . $chatID . "\n";

$token = "botxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
$getUpdate = "http://api.telegram.org/" . $token . "/getUpdates";

$url = "https://api.telegram.org/" . $token . "/sendMessage?chat_id=" . $chatID;
$url = $url . "&text=" . urlencode($msg);
$ch = curl_init();
$optArray = array(
CURLOPT_URL => $url,
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true
);
curl_setopt_array($ch, $optArray);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
}

$msg = "Hi";
$chatID = "88132232";

sendTelegram($chatID, $msg);
```

**My progress:**

1. I made a `new bot` via `@botfather` and got a `token`.
2. Then sent a message to this `bot` with my `telegram`.
3. I got `chat id` in `getUpdates`.

> https://api.telegram.org/botxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/getUpdates

and also `send message` via:

> https://api.telegram.org/botxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/sendMessage?chat_id=88132232&text=hi

It works find when i go to this url but when i want to do this dynamically it give me nothing just echo `sending message to 88132232` with no error. I searched and read many topics but no success, any idea what i missed? Before using `curl` i used `get_file_contents` but it also not worked.

Answer (score 1):

You set [CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php)

> CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER: TRUE to return the transfer as a string of the return value of curl_exec() instead of outputting it out directly.

Please return `$result` in `sendTelegram()` function, and echo it.

```
function sendTelegram($chatID, $msg) {
    // ...
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $result;
}

$result = sendTelegram($chatID, $msg);
echo $result;   // JSON String
```

Comment: so i did it, but result is: `sending message to 88132232 sending message to 88132232`. still send nothing

Comment: @Padideh try obtain chat_id from [@RawDataBot](https://t.me/RawDataBot)

Comment: See `.message.from.id` field

Comment: You mean my chat id is wrong? but as i said it works with manual url. but i did via @RawDataBot it is same `88132232`. the problem is it not send message via `curl`

Answer (score 1):

Probably you have `error` but in `curl` you should get `curl` error like this:

```
if(curl_error($ch)){
    echo 'error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
```

And most problem is `SSL`. get your error and back. but i tested your code, as @Sean said, your code working fine, try it on `php fiddle` website. if you get `SSL` error, read **[this](https://www.ultimatebeaver.com/docs/curl-error-51-ssl-no-alternative-certificate-subject-name-matches-target-host-name/)**.